# Understanding the expression for Nuclear Reaction rate

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I don't get, How the expression for Nuclear reaction rate can be written as
$$r=n_1n_2\langle \sigma v\rangle $$
where $$\langle \sigma v\rangle =\int_0^\infty \sigma(E)v f(E)dE$$
Now, $\sigma(E)$ is the probability for the nuclear reaction to occure for energy $E$ and $f(E)$ is the probability density of the particle to have energy $E$. From here, it's clear that $\sigma(E) f(E)dE$ is the probability that nuclei have energy $E$ to $E+dE$ and nuclear reaction will occure.

The object $\langle \sigma v\rangle  $ is the expectation value of velocity. I don't find how does it is related to reaction rate? Please help me understand the expression.

Comment: I am not an expert in nuclear physics, and I am confused by the use of $\sigma$ here: does it mean something other than cross-section? If it is something with dimensions other than length squared, the formula for $r$ does not yield a quantity with the dimensions of reactions per unit time per unit volume.

Comment: $\sigma(E)$ is not a probability.    It is a cross section: it has dimension Length**2 and behaves like an area.  To get a probability you need to divide by the area of the target.   $v$ is the flux factor and comes in because the faster the particles are moving the more targets they will meet.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter writes: $\sigma$ is related to reaction probability, but it's actually a cross section, with units of area.  So you are incorrect when you write "$\langle\sigma v\rangle$ is the expectation value of the velocity." The quantity $\langle\sigma v\rangle$ has units of volume per unit time.

Let's take a step back from quantum mechanics and imagine a gas of hard spheres, which only interact when they touch each other.  Each sphere has radius $r$ and cross-sectional area $\sigma = \pi r^2$.  Imagine that each sphere leaves a trail behind it of the part of the space it has touched, like a three-dimensional version of a paintbrush.  If the sphere is moving with velocity $v$, then $\sigma v$ is the rate at which new volume is added to the paint trail.

For your reaction rate, imagine that species 1 with number density $n_1$ is stationary, like nuclei in a solid, and species 2 with number density $n_2$ is moving.  If there are $N_2$ total moving spheres, the volume they sweep out is increasing at a rate $N_2 \sigma v$, and the fraction of space they have swept out is increasing at a rate $n_2 \sigma v$.  You get an interaction when the swept-out volume grows to include a new member of species 1.  That gives

$$ r = n_1 n_2 \sigma v $$

as the rate of interactions *per unit volume*.

Your definition of the average $\left<\sigma v\right>$ takes into account that $\sigma$ varies with energy, and weights the average by the population with each energy, as you've said.

I have found that most confusing questions about cross-sections can be resolved by

1. carefully squinting at the units, so I understand what I'm computing, then
2. forgetting about quantum mechanics and thinking about hard spheres.

Comment: "You get an interaction when the  swept-out volume grows to include a new member of species 1." I got that but why we multiplied with $n_1$?

Comment: The total number of interactions is going to go like the fraction of swept-out volume, $n_2\sigma v$, and like the number of targets $N_1$. By using the number density $n_1$ we get the reaction rate density. That also restores the symmetry between species 1 and 2 that we broke for our thought experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about your reply can easily find on the following book:

**Rolfs - Cauldrons in the Cosmos: Nuclear Astrophysics**

At the page number 139 you can find the answer at your question (and more and more about this fantastic relation).

> Generally, the reactions have cross sections σ(E) that depend strongly
> on center-of-mass energy $E$.
>
> This dependence is caused by a repulsive Coulomb barrier, so that:
>
> $\sigma(E) = E-1 exp(-2\pi\eta)S(E)$,
>
> for an ‘astrophysical S-factor’ $S(E)$ that is relatively less variable
> with energy.
>
> In the case of neutrons have a $\sigma(E)∝ 1/v$ behavior for
> projectile-target relative velocity $v$ near zero.
>
> Or it maybe because of resonances giving sharply peaked cross
> sections, like:
>
> $\Gamma/[(E - E_R)2 + \Gamma^2/4]$,
>
> for a single resonance centered at ER with a full width at half
> maximum of $Г$.
>
> In a stellar plasma of a mixture of two or more nuclear species, there
> will be a considerable range of relative energies $E$ (or, velocities $v$)
> because of the statistical distribution of thermal energy among all
> the particles in the plasma. The actual rate of nuclear reactions will
> therefore require an averaging of the cross sections $\sigma(E)$ over the
> thermal distribution of relative energies.
>
> We will therefore define an average reaction rate as the number of
> reactions per second per unit volume, and find an expression for this
> in terms of $\sigma(E)$ and the distribution $\phi(v)$ of the relative velocities
> of the interacting particles.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Greetings! The mathematics in your pasted material doesn't seem to have copied consistently. Please have a look at our guidance for typing mathematics ([briefly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex), [extensively](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) and make sure your answer says what it is supposed to say.

Comment: Thanks too much!